# Context initialization failed java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, nosuchmethoderror

I have downloaded all maven dependencies but on build process and I am getting following error

> Context initialization failed java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/NamedBeanHolder;
> at
> org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolveSchedulerBean(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:278)
> at
> org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.finishRegistration(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:221)
> at
> org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:200)
> at
> org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:94)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
> at
> com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
> at
> com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
> at
> com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
> at
> com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
> at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
> sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
> at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
> at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2020-10-04 15:33:42.627 [RMI
> TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO
> o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Closing GoNoGo:
> startup date [Sun Oct 04 15:32:48 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy
> 2020-10-04 15:33:42.644 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO
> c.s.g.c.d.r.RedissonCacheHelper - Shutting down Redis client...
> 2020-10-04 15:33:42.644 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] WARN
> o.s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Invocation of destroy
> method failed on bean with name 'redissonCacheHelper':
> java.lang.NullPointerException [2020-10-04 03:33:42,671] Artifact
> gonogo:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for
> details.

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" it's because the compiled library and what's there at runtime don't match.

Mostly I've seen it due to mixing a group of libraries. Make sure your spring libraries are all the same etc.

Run maven dependency:tree to see what libs are there
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html